# Navigation not woking in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am new to Angular and refer to the below questions, but there isn't any solution for my case.

- [NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270324/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-matdialogref)
- [NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef! Angular Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078977/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-matdialogref-angular-test)

I am getting the below error while routing and navigating.

```
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(UserModule)[MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:1013:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11130:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11130:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11130:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24252:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11130:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24252:1)
    at Object.get (core.js:23956:1)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:4169:1)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14660:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750:1)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27483:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569:1)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:484:1)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:469:1)
```

#### File *app.routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from "@angular/router";
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from "@angular/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "./guard/auth.guard";
import { RouterDeactivateService } from "./services/router-deactivate.service";
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './user/change-password/change-password.component';
/*Main Routing module wise with security check, we have written security check
under DI [AuthGuard], if user is log in then they may move from one module to another module.
*/

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    children: [
      { path: "", loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule) },
      {
        path: "customer",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./customer/customer.module').then(m => m.CustomerModule)
      },
      {
        path: "report",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./report/report.module').then(m => m.ReportModule)
      },
      {
        path: "policy",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canDeactivate: [RouterDeactivateService],
        loadChildren: () => import('./policy/policy.module').then(m => m.PolicyModule)
      },
      {
        path: "claim",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./claim/claim.module').then(m => m.ClaimModule)
      },
      {
        path: "mainClaim",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./mainClaim/mainClaim.module').then(m => m.MainClaimModule)
      },
      {
        path: "admin",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
      },
      {
        path: "general-report",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren:
          () => import('./general-module/general-module.module').then(m => m.GeneralModuleModule)
      },
      {
        path: "products",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./products/products.module').then(m => m.ProductsModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {
      enableTracing: false,
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

#### File *app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { AuthGuard } from './guard/auth.guard';
import { RouterDeactivateService } from './services/router-deactivate.service';
import { DataSharingService } from './shared/services/dataSharing.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthheaderService } from './shared/services/auth-header.service';
import { UploadDocumentService } from './claim/upload-document/upload-document.service';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    RouterDeactivateService,
    DataSharingService,
    AuthheaderService,
    UploadDocumentService
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### File *user.routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './change-password/change-password.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './forgot-password/forgot-password.component';

const USER_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'changePassword', component: ChangePasswordComponent },
  { path: 'forgotPassword', component: ChangePasswordComponent },
  ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(USER_ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class UserRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponent = [ChangePasswordComponent, ForgotPasswordComponent, LoginComponent]
```

#### File *user.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserRoutingModule, routingComponent } from "./user.routing.module";
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { MatPasswordStrengthModule } from '@angular-material-extensions/password-strength';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { LoginService } from "./user.service";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    UserRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatIconModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatPasswordStrengthModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    routingComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    routingComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    LoginService
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

#### File *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "<xyz>",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "<xqw>",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "10.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "10.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/forms": "10.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "10.2.1",
    "@ngui/datetime-picker": "^0.16.2",
    "@angular-material-extensions/password-strength": "^7.0.0",
    "angular7-csv": "^0.2.12",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "less": "^3.12.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker": "^0.1.4",
    "ngx-date-time-picker": "^1.1.6",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-uploader-directive": "^1.2.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "scss": "^0.2.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "10.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "10.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.5"
  }
}
```

I am using both `this.router.navigate(['changePassword']);` or `this.router.navigateByUrl('/changePassword');`, but none are navigating.

**Below is the structure of my code**

[image: Structure Image 1]

[image: Structure Image 2]

**Update part of question**

Now the injection error is resolved, but I am still not able to navigate to the changePassword component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Observable which can create an issue in navigating to the component. You can create a new method which finalizes or promises to respond when your subscribe ends successfully. So in the below code, you can use that in your case:

```
logout() {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + url, { headers: this.headers() })
            .map((res: IResponse) => {
              var json = res.json();
              json.headers = res.headers;
              return json;
            })
            .subscribe(data => {
              //DO SOMETHING, THEN ----
              resolve(data);
            }, error => reject(error));
    }).then(response => this.router.navigate(['LandingPage']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `import { Router} from '@angular/router';` and added this inside the

```js
constructor (private router: Router) {

}
```

?

The components TypeScript file that you want to navigate into changepassword component.

Comment: I want to navigate from loginComponent to change password component. router available in login component

Do i need to add router in change password component?